# Is it possible to handle iOS app distribution for another company?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, enterprise, software-distribution

Is it possible to create an app for company ABC, and distribute it to their employees only?

Apple's Enterprise program would be the best solution, but they don't have it. Is it possible to take that on for company ABC? They might have an internal server they can host files on, but no support for following through with an Enterprise solution.

Or make it available on the iTunes store, but protected with a login and password?

Comment: sure. it is possible. Company has to create an internal server & upload all the files on the server. Many companies are following this approach. Even you can use GIT for storing plist distribution files & your own server for strong ipa files. Choice is your :) For all these option you have to purchase home production account from Apple. As per my knowledge current price is $299 for a year.

Comment: Apple won't approve your app if the only way you can use it is by creating an account.  Enterprise program is the way to go.. $299 is a year is a pretty small expense for a company

Comment: "They don't have it" is a problem that is solved for $299 a year by buying an Enterprise account, much less than 1 day cost of any professional developer.

Comment: For some companies it would be like buying a car when they don't know how to drive. ;)